# Evaluates the given postfix expression with stack

Tags: java, junit

I am working to write code to Evaluate the given postfix expression. I have wrote a code, but one of the junit test doesn´t go through. How should i write that "expr contains too few operands". In the evalute I use a stack.

TODO: help to correct the "evaluate(String expr) throws ExpressionException ()" method so all the test in the testclass goes through.
EDIT: The test that i need help withy is the only in the JUNIT test class.

Interface stack:

```
/**
  * A interface of stack
  */
 public interface Stack <T> {
     /**
      * Adds the element to the top of the stack.
      */
     void push (T elem);

     /**
      * Removes and returns the top element in stack,
      * that is the element that was last added.
      * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
      */
      T pop();

     /**
      * Returns the top element in the stack without removing it.
      * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
      */
      T top();

     /**
      * Returns the number of elements in stack.
      * @return the number of elements.
      */
     int size();

     /**
      * Returns true if the stack is empty.
      * @return true.
      */
     boolean isEmpty();
 }
```

Linkedlist implements stack:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
/**
 * A singly linked list.
 *
 */
public class LinkedList<T> implements Stack <T> {
    private ListElement<T> first;   // First element in list.
    private ListElement<T> last;    // Last element in list.
    private int size;  // Number of elements in list.

    /**
     * A list element.
     */
    private static class ListElement<T>{
        public T data;
        public ListElement<T> next;

        public ListElement(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element at the beginning of this list.
     *
     * @param element An element to insert into the list.
     */
    public void addFirst(T element) {
        ListElement<T> firstElement = new ListElement<>(element);
        if (this.size == 0){
            this.first = firstElement;
            this.last = firstElement;
        }
        else{
            firstElement.next = this.first;
            this.first = firstElement;
        }
        this.size ++;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element at the end of this list.
     *
     * @param element An element to insert into the list.
     */
    public void addLast(T element) {
        ListElement<T> lastElement = new ListElement<>(element);
        if(this.size ==0){
            this.first = lastElement;
        }
        else{
            this.last.next = lastElement;
        }
        this.last = lastElement;
        this.size ++;
    }

    /**
     * @return The head of the list.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T getFirst() {
        if (this.first != null){
            return this.first.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return The tail of the list.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T getLast() {
        if(this.last != null){
            return this.last.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an element from a specified index.
     *
     * @param index A list index.
     * @return The element at the specified index.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of bounds.
     */
    public T get(int index) {
        if(index < 0|| index >= this.size){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else{
            ListElement<T>element = this.first;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                element = element.next;
            }
            return element.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first element from the list.
     *
     * @return The removed element.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty.
     */
    public T removeFirst() {
        if(this.first != null || this.size != 0){
            ListElement<T> list = this.first;
            this.first = first.next;
            size --;
            return list.data;
        }
        else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of the elements from the list.
     */
    public void clear() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.size =0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the element to the top of the stock.
     * @param elem
     */
    @Override
    public void push(T elem) {
        ListElement <T> list = new ListElement<>(elem);
        if( first == null){
            first = list;
            last = first;
        } else{
            list.next = first;
            first = list;
        }
        size ++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the top element in stack,
     * that is the element that was last added.
     * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
     * @return the top element in the stack.
     */
    @Override
    public T pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }else{
            ListElement <T> list = first;
            first = first.next;
            size --;

            return list.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns the top element in the stack without removing it.
     * Throws an EmptyStackException if stack is empty.
     * @return the top element.
     */
    @Override
    public T top() {
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }else{
            return first.data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the stock
     * @return The number of elements in the stock.
     */
    public int size() {

        return this.size;
    }

    /**
     * Note that by definition, the list is empty if both first and last
     * are null, regardless of what value the size field holds (it should
     * be 0, otherwise something is wrong).
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if this list contains no elements.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return first == null && last == null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a string representation of this list. The string
     * representation consists of a list of the elements enclosed in
     * square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the
     * characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to
     * strings by the method toString() inherited from Object.
     *
     * Examples:
     *  "[1, 4, 2, 3, 44]"
     *  "[]"
     *
     * @return A string representing the list.
     */
    public String toString() {
        ListElement<T> listOfElements = this.first;
        String returnString = "[";
        while(listOfElements != null) {
            returnString += listOfElements.data;
            if(listOfElements.next != null){
                returnString += ", ";
            }
            listOfElements = listOfElements.next;
        }
        returnString += "]";
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Postfix class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
/**
 * The Postfix class implements an evaluator for integer postfix expressions.
 *
 * Postfix notation is a simple way to define and write arithmetic expressions
 * without the need for parentheses or priority rules. For example, the postfix
 * expression "1 2 - 3 4 + *" corresponds to the ordinary infix expression
 * "(1 - 2) * (3 + 4)". The expressions may contain decimal 32-bit integer
 * operands and the four operators +, -, *, and /. Operators and operands must
 * be separated by whitespace.
 *
 */
public class Postfix {
    public static class ExpressionException extends Exception {
        public ExpressionException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the given postfix expression.
     *
     * @param expr  Arithmetic expression in postfix notation
     * @return      The value of the evaluated expression
     * @throws      ExpressionException if the expression is wrong
     */
    public static int evaluate(String expr) throws ExpressionException {

        expr = expr.trim();

        String[] tokens = expr.split("\\s+");
        if(expr.matches("(\\+)|(\\-)|(\\*)|(\\/)")){
            throw new ExpressionException("");
        }

        LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<>();

        for(String token: tokens) {
            if(isInteger(token)) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(token);
                stack.push(number);
            }
            else if(isOperator(token)) {
                String operator = token;
                int b = stack.pop();
                int a = stack.pop();
                if(token.equals("+")){
                        stack.push(a+b);
                } else if (token.equals("-")){
                    stack.push(a-b);
                }
                else if(token.equals("/")){
                    if( b == 0){
                        throw new ExpressionException("");
                    }
                    stack.push(a/b);
                } else if(token.equals("*")){
                    stack.push(a*b);
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new ExpressionException("");
            }

        }
        if(stack.size() != 1){
            throw new ExpressionException("");
        }
        int result = stack.pop();
        if(stack.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExpressionException("");
        }
        return result;
    }





    /**
     * Returns true if s is an operator.
     *
     * A word of caution on using the String.matches method: it returns true
     * if and only if the whole given string matches the regex. Therefore
     * using the regex "[0-9]" is equivalent to "^[0-9]$".
     *
     * An operator is one of '+', '-', '*', '/'.
     */
    private static boolean isOperator(String s) {
        return s.matches("[-+*/]");
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if s is an integer.
     *
     * A word of caution on using the String.matches method: it returns true
     * if and only if the whole given string matches the regex. Therefore
     * using the regex "[0-9]" is equivalent to "^[0-9]$".
     *
     * We accept two types of integers:
     *
     * - the first type consists of an optional '-'
     *   followed by a non-zero digit
     *   followed by zero or more digits,
     *
     * - the second type consists of an optional '-'
     *   followed by a single '0'.
     */
    private static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        return s.matches("(((\\-)*?[1-9](\\d+)*)|(\\-)*?0)");
    }
}
```

Junit class

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * Test class for Postfix
 *
 */
public class PostfixTest {
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);

    
  
    @Test
    public void evaluateExceptionWhenExprContainsTooFewOperands() {
        String[] expressions = {"1 +", " 1 2 + +"};
        assertExpressionExceptionOnAll(expressions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: @Progman I have edited it now.

Comment: Your `new ExpressionException("")` class shouldn't have an empty string as a description/error message for the exception. An empty error message is not helpful. Instead you should add an actual error description so when you get an `ExpressionException` you will see error message like "The divisor cannot be zero".

Comment: @Progman I know but thats not what i need help with. What I need help with is to write in code in the postfix that will make this last test go through

Answer (score 0):

Your `pop()` method will throw an exception when the stack is empty (which you can catch) and your `isEmpty()` method will return `true` when the stack is empty. You can also use the `size()` method to check the number of items on the stack. As an example, you can use code like this to check if there are enough values to run your operand:

```
// ...
else if(isOperator(token)) {
    String operator = token;
    if (stack.size() < 2) {
        throw new ExpressionException("There are not enough values on the stack to perform the operation");
    }
    int b = stack.pop();
    int a = stack.pop();
    // ...
```